# Setting table position

Tags: tables

For example it's the end of a text. How can I relocate table to the top of the page? Evidently that really big space looks strange. I tried using [h!], [bhtp] etc., nothing helped.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}                   % поиск в PDF
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           % кодировка
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % кодировка исходного текста
\usepackage[english]{babel} % локализация и переносы
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
}

\author{E.S.Tsyrendorzhisev}
\title{Battle for Britain}
\date{}

\usepackage{extsizes} % Возможность сделать 14-й шрифт
\usepackage{geometry} % Простой способ задавать поля
\usepackage{multirow}

\geometry{top=25mm}
\geometry{bottom=35mm}
\geometry{left=35mm}
\geometry{right=20mm}

\usepackage{setspace} % Интерлиньяж
\onehalfspacing % Интерлиньяж 1.5

\begin{document} % Конец преамбулы, начало текста.

\maketitle

\section{Mission 2.1}

\subsection{Posters}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Poster demonstrates soldiers loading gun. So i see poster calling to beat enemies.
    \item Poster refers to Nazi greeding and demonstrates Hitler surrendering.
    \item Poster shows us women with kid starving and calls for making contribution.
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Questions}
\paragraph{Person 1}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item She is working now.
    \item I saw her right now.
    \item She drew.
    \item I saw her drawing.
    \item I heard her swearing.
\end{enumerate}
\paragraph{Person 2}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item She's at home.
    \item I didn't see her.
    \item She wrote code.
    \item I saw her writing code.
    \item I saw her singing.
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Appendix}
\paragraph{a}
I saw him drawing.
\paragraph{b}
no answer


\section{Mission 2.2}
\subsection{Exercises}
\paragraph{1}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Don't put the dictionary away. I am using it.
    \item Don't put the dictionary away. I need it.
    \item Who is that man? What does he want?
    \item Who is that man? Why is looking at us?
    \item Alan says he's 80 years old, but nobody believes him.
    \item She told me her name, but I do not remember it now.
    \item I am thinking of selling my car. Would you be interested in buying it?
    \item I think you should sell your car. You don't use it very often.
    \item Air consists mainly nitrogen and oxygen.
\end{enumerate}
\paragraph{2}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item I am very busy today.
    \item At noon I am visiting my friend.
    \item We want to have lunch together.
    \item In the afternoon I am playing squash with Emily.
    \item In the evening, I am meeting Rob.
    \item We are going to the cinema.
    \item The film starts at 8 pm.
\end{enumerate}
\paragraph{3}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Look! He's leaving the house.
    \item Quiet please! I am writing a test.
    \item She usually walks to school. But look! Today she's going by bike.
    \item Every Sunday we go to see my grandparents.
    \item He often goes to the cinema.
    \item We're playing Monopoly at the moment.
    \item The child seldom cries.
    \item I am not doing anything at the moment.
    \item Does he watch the news regularly.
\end{enumerate}
\subsection{Appendix}
\paragraph{a} Present Continuous use is for temporary or new habits.
\begin{itemize}
    \item He's eating a lot these days.
    \item She's swimming every morning.
    \item You're smoking too much.
\end{itemize}

It uses for habits that are not regular, but they happen very often. We use the present continuous in this way to talk about annoying habit. 
\begin{itemize}
    \item You're forever losing your keys!
    \item She's constantly missing the train.
    \item Lucy's always smiling!
\end{itemize}

\paragraph{b}
\textit{Wanting} is used as a participle, as adjective, not a main verb.
\begin{itemize}
    \item I remember him wanting of a new toy.
    \item I know you're still there watching me wanting me.
\end{itemize}

\section{Intermediate}
\subsection{Practice}

\textipa{In DIs greIv 'aU@, p@'\ae hps D@ m@Ust 'feItfUl In 'hIst@ri, aI s\textepsilon nd tu: '\textepsilon vri 'haUsh@Uld \textturna v maI 'pi:plz, b@UT \ae t h@Um \ae nd @Uv@'si:z, DIs 'm\textepsilon sI\textdyoghlig, 'sp@Uk@n wID D@ seIm d\textepsilon pD \textturna v 'fi:lIN f\textopeno :r i:\textteshlig w\textturnv n \textturna v ju: \ae z If aI w\textepsilon:r 'eIbl tu: kr\textturna s j\textopeno: 'Tr\textepsilon\textesh h@Uld \ae nd spi:k tu: ju: maI's\textepsilon lf. f\textopeno D@ 's\textepsilon k@nd taIm In D@ lIvz \textturna m@Ust \textturna v \textturnv s, wi: a:r \ae t w\textopeno}

\section{Mission 2.3}
\subsection{Excercises}
\paragraph{1}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item I've lost my keys, so I can't open that door.
    \item Columbus arrived in the New World in 1492.
    \item Nina's broken her leg. She's still in hospiutal.
    \item I've lived here all my life.
    \item Colin left for Brazil this morning.
    \item Last winter Robin stayed with his father in the Alps for three days.
    \item Ellen's always written with her left hand.
    \item She did a language course in Paris last summer.
    \item Have anyone phoned yet?
    \item I've seen Paul today, but I didn't see him last Sunday.
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{2}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Emma has never seen this film before.
    \item How often has she phoned the office this morning?
    \item Have the Millers arrived yet?
    \item John has never gone on a trip through Alaska.
    \item Have they ever been to New York?
    \item Andy hasn't repaired sister's bike.
    \item I've bought a new laptop.
    \item Have Toby found his blue pen yet?
    \item The students haven't forgotten their homework so far.
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{3}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item The police arrested two people early this morning.
    \item She went to Japan but now she's come back.
    \item Dan have already bought two tablets this year.
    \item How many game has your team won so far this season?
    \item Did you visit the CN Tower when you were staying in Toronto.
    \item There has been an accident in High Street, so we have to use King Street to get to your school.
    \item I have not seen Peter since I arrived last Tuesday.
    \item Frank got his bike last May. So he's had it for 4 months.
    \item I'm sorry, I didn't write earlier, but i have been working a lot lately. 
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Appendix}
\paragraph{a}
We use this tense when we want to talk about unfinished actions or states or habits that started in the past and continue to the present.
\paragraph{b} Same answer becaue the fixed time can be another action, which is in the past simple.

\subsection{Research}
By 1720, the English colonists, inhabitants of the New World, began to notice that their language was quite different from that spoken in Great Britain. The reasons are numerous, the most obvious being the sheer distance from England. Over the years, many words were borrowed from the Native Americans, as well as other immigrants from France, Germany, Spain, and other countries. Other words that became obsolete across the pond, continued to be utilized in the colonies. In other cases, words simply had to be created in order to explain the unfamiliar landscape, weather, animals, plants, and living conditions that these early pioneers encountered.
Newly independent Americans were proud of their “new” American language, wearing it, as yet, another badge of independence. In 1789, Noah Webster wrote in his Dissertations on the English Language: “The reasons for American English being different than English English are simple: As an independent nation, our honor requires us to have a system of our own, in language as well as government.”
However "the distinction between Simple Past (SP) and Present Perfect (PP) is a fairly recent development in English. Since the distinction was not clear-cut in British English (BrE) when the first settlers arrived in America, its scarcity in American English (AmE) hasbeen interpreted as an aspect of colonial lag. Data from late Modern English indicate that this is not really the case. The long-range, corpus-based study by Elsness (1997) shows that the PP increases over time but starts decreasing again from the second half of the eighteenth century. This development is led by AmE, but the decrease starts from a higher level than in BrE. Previous corpus-based studies of PDE – whenever they included regional variation – have consistently shown that the PP is more commonly used in BrEthan in AmE.
Evidence from the Brown family of corpora might show that this is no longer the case. Elsness (2009: 242), based on the untagged version of the Brown quartet and a study of 20 frequently used verbs, provides preliminary evidence that the decrease of the PP continues into the second half of the twentieth century. He points at a regional difference, namely that the decline is slowing down in AmE and that BrE is approaching the level of AmE. In other words, the two national varieties appear to be converging in their use of the PP.

\section{Pre-Shadowing}

\subsection{YouTube channels}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \href{https://www.youtube.com/user/oxford}{University of Oxford}
    \item \href{https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQfMyugsjrVUWU0v_ZxQs2Q}{Machine Tech Video Blog}
    \item \href{https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcqQi9LT0ETkRoUu8eYaEkg}{Fluid Mechanics 101}
    \item \href{https://www.youtube.com/user/sentdex}{sentdex}
    \item \href{https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRaiKJHsh_Ii4H-86uqXT_g}{VDEngineering}
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Practice}

\begin{itemize}

    \item \href{https://www.youtube.com/user/oxford}{University of Oxford}: \href{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3c5tYfPD5gw}{Are we wrecking the deep sea?}
    \begin{enumerate}   
        \item \href{https://youtu.be/3c5tYfPD5gw?t=3}{0:03} Word \textit{diversity} in BrE is pronounced as \textipa{[daI'v\textepsilon :sIti]}. AmE variant is \textipa{[dI'v\textepsilon rs@ti]}.

        \item \href{https://youtu.be/3c5tYfPD5gw?t=5}{0:05} Word \textit{curl} in BrE is pronounced as \textipa{[k\textepsilon:l]}. AmE variant is \textipa{[k\textepsilon rl]}.

        \item \href{https://youtu.be/3c5tYfPD5gw?t=19}{0:19} Word \textit{recording} in BrE is pronounced as \textipa{[rI'k\textopeno:diN]}. AmE variant is \textipa{[r@'k\textopeno rdIN]}.

        \item \href{https://youtu.be/3c5tYfPD5gw?t=22}{0:22} Word \textit{obviously} in BrE is pronounced as \textipa{['\textturna bvI@sli]}. AmE variant is \textipa{['abvi@sli]}.

        \item \href{https://youtu.be/3c5tYfPD5gw?t=43}{0:43} Word \textit{all} in BrE is pronounced as \textipa{['\textopeno:l]}. AmE variant is \textipa{[\textopeno l]}.
    \end{enumerate}

    \item \href{https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQfMyugsjrVUWU0v_ZxQs2Q}{Machine Tech Video Blog}: \href{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PobAcrfPzuU&t=9s}{Compression Packing}
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item \href{https://youtu.be/PobAcrfPzuU?t=30}{0:30} Word \textit{shaft} in AmE is pronounced as \textipa{[\textesh\ae ft]}. BrE variant is \textipa{[\textesh a:ft]}.

        \item \href{https://youtu.be/PobAcrfPzuU?t=42}{0:42} Word \textit{chamber} in AmE is pronounced as \textipa{['\textteshlig eImb@r]}. BrE variant is \textipa{['\textteshlig eImb@]}.

        \item \href{https://youtu.be/PobAcrfPzuU?t=72}{1:12} Word \textit{shaft} in AmE is pronounced as \textipa{[t\ae sk]}. BrE variant is \textipa{[ta:sk]}.

        \item \href{https://youtu.be/PobAcrfPzuU?t=444}{7:24} Word \textit{redirect} in AmE is pronounced as \textipa{[.rid@'r\textepsilon kt]}. BrE variant is \textipa{[.ri:dI'r\textepsilon kt]}.

        \item \href{https://youtu.be/PobAcrfPzuU?t=520}{8:40} Word \textit{periodically} in AmE is pronounced as \textipa{[,piri'adIk@li]}. BrE variant is \textipa{[,pI@rI'\textturna dIk@li]}.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}

\section{Mission 2.4}
\subsection{Exercises}
\paragraph{1}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Have you been swimming?
    \item How long have you been waiting?
    \item What have you been doing?
    \item How long have you been working here?
    \item How long have you been selling mobile phones?
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{2}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item It has been raining for two hours.
    \item We have been waiting for 20 minutes.
    \item I have been learning since December.
    \item She's been working since 18 January.
    \item They started going for years.
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{3}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Maria has been learning English for two years.
    \item I have been looking for you.
    \item Why are you looking at me like that?
    \item She has been teaching for ten years.
    \item I have been thinking about what you said and I've decided to take your advice.
    \item No, he's working.
    \item She has been working very hard recently.
\end{itemize}

\paragraph{4}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item How long has he been learning Arabic?
    \item Have you been studying long?
    \item Have you caught any fish?
    \item How many people have you invited?
    \item How long have you been teaching?
    \item How many books have you written?
    \item How long have you been writing books?
    \item How long have you been saving?
    \item How much money have you saved? 
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{5}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item I've played tennis.
    \item Somebody has broken window.
    \item Have you been working hard?
    \item Have you ever been in a factory?
    \item Where has she gone?
    \item I have not been waiting long.
    \item It stopped.
    \item I've lost my phone. Have you seen it anywhere?
    \item I've been reading the book you lent me, but I've not finished it yet.
    \item I've read the book you lent me, so you can have it back now.
    \item I've had it since I was a child
\end{enumerate}

\section{Mission 2.5}
\subsection{Exercises}
\paragraph{1}
\begin{itemize}
    \item used to have
    \item used to live
    \item used to eat
    \item used to be
    \item used to take
    \item used to be
    \item did you use to go
\end{itemize}
\paragraph{2}

\begin{itemize}
    \item She used to travel a lot.
    \item She used to have lots of friends.
    \item She used to be very lazy.
    \item She used to be a hotel receptionist.
    \item She used to play the piano.
    \item She never used to read newspapers.
    \item She didn't use to drink tea.
    \item She used to have a dog.
\end{itemize}

\paragraph{3}

\begin{itemize}
    \item I used to have a sweet tooth, but now I cut down on sugar.
    \item I didn't use to learn English, but now I have classes.
    \item I used to be arrogant person, but I am good guy.
    \item I didn't used to help people, but I do now.
\end{itemize}

\paragraph{4}

\begin{enumerate}   
    \item When Jack started working in this job, he wasn't \textbf{used to} driving two hours to work every morning, but after some time he \textbf{got used to} it. Now it's no problem for him. He is used to driving two hours every morning. 
    \item Julia is a nurse. A year ago she started working nights. At first she found it hard and didn't like it. She \textbf{was not used to working} nights and it took her a few months to \textbf{get used to} it. Now, after a year, it's OK for her. She \textbf{is used to working} nights.
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{5}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item I am used to sleeping
    \item I'm used to working long hours.
    \item I am not used to going to bed very late.
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{6}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item drinking
    \item eating
    \item having
    \item have
    \item go
    \item be
    \item being
    \item live, living
\end{enumerate}

\section{Teaching 1.3}

\subsection{Exercises}
\paragraph{1}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item An eagle is a bird.
    \item English is a language.
    \item Moscow is a city.
    \item Russia is a country.
    \item Europe is a continent.
    \item A dictionary is a book.
    \item The hotel is a building.
    \item A cat is an animal.
    \item A bee is an insect.
    \item A banana is a fruit.
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{2}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Spring is a season.
    \item April is a warm mouth.
    \item Summer and winter are seasons.
    \item September and October are cold month.
    \item A niece is a relative.
    \item Grandparents are relatives.
    \item Forbes is a magazine.
    \item The Times and Kommersant are newspapers.
    \item Her father is a stupid man.
    \item Aeroflot is an airline.
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{3}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Russian is difficult language.
    \item The Sun is a star.
    \item The students in my class aren't very friendly.
    \item I have a dog and a cat. The dog is usually dirty but the cat is always clean.
    \item I really like the local food.
    \item His wife is a beautiful woman.
    \item The windows in our house are large.
    \item It's an awful idea. 
    \item Beach at the end of the street.
    \item The answers are in the book.
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{4}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item My brother is in the kitchen.
    \item He's a russian businessman.
    \item It's an expensive restaurant.
    \item The wind is strong today.
    \item Excuse me, where is the station?
    \item I go to work by bus.
    \item Don't worry. It's just a joke.
    \item He's usually at work at the weekend.
    \item I have a flat and a house. The flat is big but the house is quite small.
    \item Everest is a mountain. 
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{5}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item My cousin is a designer.
    \item It's a cheap cafe.
    \item The movie is too long.
    \item The local market is next to the station.
    \item Where is the airport.
    \item The coffee is very hot.
    \item Where are the children?
    \item 100\$ is a good price.
    \item When is your flight?
    \item This road is quite dangerous.
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Appendix}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item В комнату вошёл мальчик.
    \item Мальчик вошёл в комнату.
    \item В комнату вошёл мальчик.
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Block II}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
\end{enumerate}

\section{s}
\subsection{Exercises}
\paragraph{1}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item When
    \item If
    \item If
    \item if
    \item When
    \item if
    \item when
    \item if
    \item if
    \item if
    \item When
    \item If
    \item when
    \item when
    \item if
    \item if
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{2}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item I finish
    \item it's
    \item I'll be, leaves
    \item stops
    \item We'll come, we're
    \item I'll bring
    \item I'm
    \item gets
    \item I'll tell, I'm
    \item give
    \item is
    \item I'll call
    \item I'll be surprised
    \item Will you go, invite
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{3}
\begin{enumerate}

    \item you finish university
    \item I'll be the most lavish guy in this world
    \item you do it
    \item I'll be so challenged
    \item I return
    \item it's good weather
    \item you don't hurry
    \item you do your homework
    \item It'll be easier to wake up
    \item you don't watch it
    \item she ignores preparation
    \item I help you
    \item you're good boy
    \item he's Jeckyll\&Hyde
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{4}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item If you pass the exam you'll get a certificate.
    \item If you fail the exam you can do it again.
    \item If you don't want this magazine I'll throw it away.
    \item If you want those picture you can have them.
    \item If you're busy now we can talk later.
    \item If you're hungry we can have lunch now.
    \item If you need money I can lend you some.
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{5}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item When you're in London again, come and see us.
    \item I want see Sophie before she goes out.
    \item Call me when you know what time you're going to get there.
    \item I'm going out now. Will you be here when I get back?
    \item I think everything will be fine. but if there are any problems, I'll call you, OK?
    \item We must do it something soon before it's too late.
    \item Anna looks different now. When you see her again, you won't recognize her.
    \item Steve has applied for the job, but he isn't really qualified for it. I'll be surprised if he gets it.
    \item I'm going to be away for a few days. If you'll need me to contact me while I am away. here's my number.
    \item I don't want to go without you. I'll wait until you're ready.
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{6}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item When I find somewhere to live I'll give you address.
    \item After I do shopping I'll come straight back home.
    \item Let's go home before it gets dark.
    \item I won't speak her until she apologise to me.
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{7}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Do you have time to look at some picture before go?
    \item Can you let me know as soon as you decide?
    \item Where're you going to stay when you're there?
    \item I think things will be better when they build a new road.
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Appendix}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item I am doing homework now. I'm visiting classes today in VB.
    \item I've never watched that movie. But I've read really positive review.
    \item I was shy guy. It freaked out me but I put up with it and lived my boring and gray life.
    \item I visit my classes every week. It makes me a little annoyed to use metro for it.
    \item I'll live better than now. I'll accomplish this target regardless any obstacles.
\end{enumerate}

\section{Conditionals}
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}

\begin{table}[p]
    \centering
    \caption{Conditional rule table}
    \label{tbl:conditional}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Cond 1 & Future  & \multirow{3}{*}{If} & Present      & Will       \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
        Cond 2 & Present &                     & Past         & Would      \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
        Cond 3 & Past    &                     & Past Perfect & Would have \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document} % Конец текста.
```

Comment: please copy paste your latex code  staring with `document class` and finishing at `end document`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I see it, the main issue is that the sectioning header and the `tabular` material should appear on the same page. Put differently, the `tabular` shouldn't "float" -- in the LaTeX-specific sense of the word -- at all. The fact that, in your test document, the table is placed in the middle of page 18 rather than at the top is somewhat secondary, in my opinion. (By the way, your code features the instruction `\begin{table}[p]`, virtually assuring that the table object will get placed on a page all by itself, centered vertically.)

If this interpretation/opinion is correct, I suggest you (a) load the `caption` package in the preamble, (b) replace the `table` environment with a `center` environment and omit the `\centering` instruction, and (c) replace `\caption{...}` with `\captionof{table}{...}`.

[image]

For the (not exactly minimal...) test document you posted, the section header and table will actually both fit at the bottom of page 17.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
%\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}  % not needed for this example
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tipa}

\usepackage{extsizes} % Возможность сделать 14-й шрифт
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=25mm,bottom=35mm,left=35mm,right=20mm}
\usepackage{multirow,caption}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

%% it's nice to have the 'array' package:
\usepackage{array}

% Load 'hyperref' package last:
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,filecolor=magenta,urlcolor=blue}

\author{E.S.Tsyrendorzhisev}
\title{Battle for Britain}
\date{}
\begin{document}   
\maketitle

\dots

\setcounter{section}{9} % just for this example

\section{Conditionals}
\begin{center}
    \captionof{table}{Conditional rule table}
    \label{tbl:conditional}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Cond 1 & Future  & \multirow{3}{*}{If} & Present      & Will       \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
        Cond 2 & Present &                     & Past         & Would      \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
        Cond 3 & Past    &                     & Past Perfect & Would have \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```